# Не работает обращения к DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, html, вёрстка

Код:

```
function razvorot(num) {
    var w = 50;
    var w2 = 50;
    if (num = 1) {
        while (w < 100) {
            w++;
            w2--;
            document.getElementById('kortush').width = w + '%';
            document.getElementById('kandi').width = w2 + '%';
            console.log('mod1:w = ' + w + '; w2 = ' + w2);
        }
    } else {
        while (w < 100) {
            w++;
            w2--;
            document.getElementById('kandi').width = w + '%';
            document.getElementById('kortush').width = w2 + '%';
            console.log('mod2:w = ' + w + '; w2 = ' + w2);
        }
    }
}
```

В консоль выводиться всё как надо. Но вот сами элементы #kandi и #kortush не изменяются. В chrome смотрю код. Действительно ничего не поменялось. И так в каждом браузере! Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изменять стили элементов, нужно оперировать со свойством style:

```
document.getElementById(ID).style.width = '100px';
```

Обязательно указывайте, в каком формате вы подставляете числа (px, em, %, etc)